# Does every flutter app contain Flutter engine?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to digest the following information from Flutter site.

> **How does Flutter run my code on Android?**
>
> The engine’s C and C++ code are compiled with Android’s NDK. The Dart
> code (both the SDK’s and yours) are ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled into
> native, ARM, and x86 libraries. Those libraries are included in a
> “runner” Android project, and the whole thing is built into an APK.
> When launched, the app loads the Flutter library. Any rendering,
> input, or event handling, and so on, is delegated to the compiled
> Flutter and app code. This is similar to the way many game engines
> work.

Is each Flutter app (more precisely each Android app that is created with Flutter) published with Flutter engine attached?

Comment: just check what constains apk ... i'm pretty sure that every apk contains `libflutter.so`

Comment: `.so` is library ... `libflutter.so` is flutter engine itself

Comment: well "lot of space" is relative ... but yes, it will take some space but ... it's up to 10MB for one ABI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is included in every app. There is no code sharing between apps on Android/iOS. Also each app could have a different version of the engine (depending on when it was compiled)

Note that the with the upcoming Flutter 1.0, the overhead (on Android) is less than 5M, which is not bad. I believe the overhead is similar on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

libflutter.so is 27.1MB on my emulator for each of a full / production app and a hello world app.

Comment: This is case when there is no split for processor architures

Comment: Make sure you check in release mode. It should be a lot smaller (I believe 27.1mb is in debug mode)